# React Native wrapping Text oddly

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, expo, word-wrap

I am trying to render a line of text inside a view in my component. But the text is not wrapping correctly on word level but randomly going to new line. I think it is trying to fit a longer line on a new line but that is not what I want. This is an Expo app.

If standard Text tag is not good for this then is there some other alternative?

This is my component:

**Request Item**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { MarkdownView } from "react-native-markdown-view";
import Tag from "../common/Tag";
import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";
import styles from "./Styles";

const RequestItem = ({ type, title, priority, creator, rid, createDate, dueDate }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.RequestContainer}>
      <View>
        <Tag title={type} color={type === "S" ? Colors.BlueAccent : Colors.GreenAccent} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.RequestTitleContainer}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.RequestTitle}>
            {`${title} `}
            <Tag
              title={priority}
              color={
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-nested-ternary
                priority === "High"
                  ? Colors.RedAccent
                  : priority === "Medium"
                  ? Colors.BlueAccent
                  : Colors.GreenAccent
              }
            />
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "red" }}>
            {`**${creator}** created the request with id: **${rid}** on 
              **${createDate}** due on **${dueDate}**`}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default RequestItem;
```

**Styles**

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  RequestContainer: {
    borderColor: Colors.GrayAccent,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    margin: 10,
    padding: 4,
  },
  RequestTitle: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  RequestTitleContainer: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
});

export default styles;
```

As you can see here, the line of text **Aug 7, 2018** can easily fit on the previous line. Still starting from it, the content was wrapped to a new line. Why is this?

I tried usig flex-wrap: "wrap", but that did not help.

I wanted to wrap the text at word level. How do I go about it?

[image: Screenshot of weird wrapping]

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a new line inside the string you are trying to print. Tapping `ENTER` inside backticks (``) will trigger a new line. So what's following next will be displayed on a new line.

Example:

```
console.log(`something
    else`);
```

Will print on 2 lines.

Comment: yeah I figured it out. In trying to have less charaacters per line, I got in this  issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the problem was with this line:

{`**${creator}** created the request with id: **${rid}** on 
  **${createDate}** due on **${dueDate}**`}

Since I broke it down in 2 parts with enter this was happening.